# error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment tail->getnext() = a;

Tags: c++, class

My code is below as well as the description of my problem:

```
 class node
{
 public:
 node(float val1, node* next1)
 : val(val1), next(next1) {   }
 node(int val1)
 :val(val1), next(NULL) {   }
 node() {  }
 float getvalue() { return val;}
 node* getnext() { return next;}  

 private:
 float  val;
 node* next;
 };

class linkedlist
{ public:
  linkedlist(): head(NULL), tail(NULL) { }
  node* addnode(node* a)
 {


     tail->getnext() = a;
     tail = a;

  }  

 float printlist()
 {
   node* tmp = head;
   while(tmp!=NULL)
  {
     std::cout << tmp->getvalue() << std::endl;
     tmp = tmp->getnext();
  }

 }
 private :
 node* head;
 node* tail;

 };
 int main()
{


 }
```

Could anyone help me fix the error? I just want to set `tail->next = a`, but 
as next is a private value, I can't do this. I've been using `tail->getnext() = a`, but then the error occurs. Why does the error occur?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you please reduce that to a [MCVE]. Remove all the irrelevant stuff first pleae!

Comment: `getnext()` returns a copy of `next`, so the assignment can't modify the original value try returning a reference as in:  `node*& getnext() { return next;} `.

Comment: Richard : yes, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node::genNext ()` returns a pointer an it is an R-value, so you cannot assign anything to it.

To do this, you have to return a *reference* to the pointer, which is a modifiable L-value:

```
 node*& getnext() { return next;}
```